# Retaining data for each dynamically added fragment in view pager

Tags: android

I am working on a project  in which I have used a `ViewPager`. In that `ViewPager` the fragments are populated dynamically.

It's an app that covers functionality like shopping and adding items to cart. Each fragment shows data in a list view and in each row there is quantity and amount of the item to be displayed with plus and minus button to increase and decrease the quantity.

My list view is in a fragment that belongs to the `ViewPager`. Below that fragment I have text views where I want to show the total quantity and total amount according to the items chosen. I am able to do so far for each fragment successfully.

But I am getting stuck at a point that I am able to achieve this thing for an individual fragment. As soon as I swipe the fragment and next fragment comes and I click on plus or minus button for quantity, the data in the text views takes the second fragment data while the data of previous fragment is getting lost. I want the previous data in the text views getting added to new data.

I have been searching for the resolution since 5-6 days but no success so far. I have surfed internet. I know we can find the current fragment but how can that help us?? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post some code snippets relating to the problem you are experiencing. Also consider reading [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There is function available to retain the pager in memory you can easily set the dynamic data length in it to get your required results.

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int lenghOfData)
```

You can take reference from here,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Answer (score 0):

Move your **textviews** to activity. Create a method like `setText(int quantity)` and set text of `TextView` and hold total quantity and total amount datas in activity. In xml, move `TextView` definiton to activity xml below `ViewPager` or anywhere not to disturb your design. When click button call `setText` method or other methods you want to use for each fragment.

Comment: I am using a navigation drawer.In Navigation drawer  there is first fragment called "pos fragment".In that fragment there is a viewpager that further has a fragment to be inflated dynamically.The textviews are there in the POS fragment.